# ¿Cómo puedo nombrar data frames conforme elementos de una lista?

Tags: r, lista

estoy buscando nombrar data frames basados en información que tengo de una lista, es decir:

defino una lista como :

```
lista <- c("financiero", "economista", "matematico")
```

me gustaría generar tres data frames automáticamente cuyo nombre sea cada elemento de dicha lista

es decir algo como:

```
financiero <- 10
economista <- 5
matematico <- 20
```

Pero de una forma automática ya que eso es un ejemplo pero tengo una lista mucho más grande que dificulta hacerlo a mano. Muchas gracias de antemano por el apoyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto dispones de una función muy útil: [assign()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html), con la que podrías hacer algo así:

```
assign("financiero", 10)
financiero
[1] 10
```

Lo que hace esta función es "asignar" una nueva variable al entorno actual con el valor indicado en el segundo parámetro. Hay que tener en cuenta que los nombres respeten la semántica del lenguaje y que no sirve para establecer valores de elementos en particular de un vector, lista, etc.

Si tienes múltiples valores para asignar desde una lista, podrías implementar un ciclo para hacerlo:

```
variables_nombres <- c("financiero", "economista", "matematico")
variables_valores <- c(10, 5, 20)

for(x in 1:length(variables_nombres)){
    assign(variables_nombres[x], variables_valores[x])
}
```